# Why is CREATE TABLE command not working in a user-defined transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I apologise in advance for this stupid question, but I cannot figure why CREATE TABLE is not rolled back in the code shown below. I know that CREATE DATABASE, CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG, CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX cannot be specified witnin user-defined transaction. Please note that Tables folder within SSMS gets locked whilst executing this code.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
CREATE TABLE temp
(
chisla char(1)
)

SELECT count(chisla) AS Count, chisla AS My_Numbers
FROM temp
--GROUP BY chisla
ORDER BY chisla

drop table temp
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
GO
```

Comment: From what I can see, this script shouldn't even start. You are mixing aggregated and non-aggregated columns without using GROUP BY, so you should receive an error message before the script runs.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'temp.chisla' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: But the error message is irrelevant. The main idea of BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT TRANSACTION to rollback all actions in case of error. But rollback is not happening and the question is why there is no rollback.

Comment: @Pavel - No, you need error trapping for that.  You are referring to a `TRY...CATCH` block, I think.

Comment: @JNK: I think he cannot use `TRY...CATCH` either. The script just won't start, and so the error cannot be intercepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell it to rollback. JNK shows how the try Catch shoudl be done to rollback a transacation in case of a trappable error. However in this case with incorrect SQL, it wouldn't rollback in any event because it is a non-trappable error. You must have correct syntax in the SQl for transactions to work correctly which is one reason why dynamic SQl can be very dangerous as it is impossible to fully test.

It is a bad practice to be creating tables on the fly like this anyway. If you want something temporaily, use a temp table or table variable, do not create a permanent table that you expect to rollback the creating of if the action fails.

Comment: +1 - Though in some instances a materialized temp table can be a benefit (if you need a large one on a shared server with a lot of activity on tempdb, for instance).

Comment: In case of temp table instead of table result will be exactly the same. Originally it was #temp, I have inserted another version of code here. But anyway I have found in your answer what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `TRY...CATCH` Block.  There's a very nice explanation [here on msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296.aspx)

For a quick example, though:

```
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
   ...your code...
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ...error reporting code here...
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Nice code to show how to correctly set up rollback code. However, this won't work for his problem as the error is a non-trappable error. Try this code and you will see: begin try
begin tran
create table dbo.rollbacktest (test int)

select count(*), test from dbo.rollbacktest

commit tran
end try

Begin catch
rollback tran
print 'rolling back'
select * from dbo.rollbacktest
end catch;
--drop table dbo.rollbacktest